# Building an aggregate mySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently building an aggregate mySQL table which is build based on 4 different tables. The largest table (accel) has 7.8mil rows and the other 3 have less than 5mil rows. The tables that I am using have duplicate rows i.e.

```
creatorId,             capabilities, frequency_MHz, rssi, dutyCycleLevel
'X^6%g9#tg!Q:]0uqkwcOc)==', '[WEP]',      '2412',    '-72', '-3733'
'X^6%g9#tg!Q:]0uqkwcOc)==', '[WEP]',      '2437',    '-54', '-3733'
```

All 4 tables contain a creatorId and a dutyCycleLevel. Depending on the other values stored in other columns, I am doing some operations on the values and then copying the result in my new table. Everything has to be grouped by the creatorId and the dutyCycleLevel of one main table (namely 'accel') such that we only get one final creatorId along with one final dutyCycleLevel for all the duplicates (i.e. if 'abc' appears 10 times in 10 different rows, 'abc' will only appear once in the final table). The problem that I am encountering is the huge processing time to build the table. I have left my machine overnight and it is still not completed (it has been running for 24 hours now). Here is my query:

```
DROP TABLE `BoxCounting_aggregate`;
CREATE TABLE `SHED5`.`BoxCounting_aggregate` (
  `creatorId` VARCHAR(55) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `timestamp` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `latitude` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `longitude` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `norm_accel` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `std_dev_accel` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `batteryStatus` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `wifi_seen` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `dutyCycle` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT ''
  );
  INSERT INTO BoxCounting_aggregate
  (
  creatorId, timestamp, latitude, longitude, norm_accel, std_dev_accel, batteryStatus, wifi_seen, dutyCycle
  )
  (
  SELECT 
  location.creatorId, 
  location.timestamp, 
  sqrt(pow(AVG(accel.accel_x),2)+pow(AVG(accel.accel_y),2)+pow(AVG(accel.accel_z),2)), 
  STD(accel.accel_z),
  case battery.pluggedInDescription 
    when 'Not Plugged' then 0
    when 'Plugged USB' then 0.5
    when 'Plugged AC' then 1
    else null
    end,
  COUNT(wifi.dutyCycleLevel), 
  location.dutyCycleLevel
  FROM SHED5.location, SHED5.accel, SHED5.wifi, SHED5.battery
  GROUP BY location.creatorId, location.dutyCycleLevel
  );
```

I am grouping by creatorId and dutyCycle level since those two columns are the most important to keep record of. I am using AVG on latitude and longitude since I want the averaged location of all the records stored in the table. Like I said, creatorId and dutyCycleLevel appear multiple times. I do not think there is anything syntactically wrong with my query but it is definitely an inefficient way of doing what I am trying to do. All 4 tables have indexes but do not have primary keys since, by having creatorId as the main column containing duplicates, I cannot use it as the primary key. Any suggestions for improving the processing time? or anything that I have to sintactically change to the query?

Comment: You are creating the Cartesian product of 4 tables equating to roughly 120million rows, then (with no index) you are trying to summarize. Are you sure your JOINs (which BTW you should get in the habit of using `JOIN`, not the comma syntax) should NOT be using some sort of relation? An additional comment: I would be wary of any columns that are not either used in your `GROUP BY` clause or an aggregate (SUM, COUNT, etc) function.

Comment: How can it possibly result in roughly 120mil rows? If we have duplicate rows that we are grouping by, shouldn't the resulting table be less than i.e. 500k? I ran a query once on one table (the one with 7.8mil rows) and it resulted in 98k rows using GROUP BY.

Comment: My mistake: I meant 1Billion (not 120M): 8M * 5M * 5M * 5M. Not meant as an insult- but do you understand what the implications of Cartesian product is and that the GROUPing only occurs after the Cartesian product occurs?

Comment: I see what you mean now but it should not do that. The GROUP BY function is similar to using DISTINCT but allows operations to be done on the data from what I know. That is why I mentioned the case when I got only 98k rows using GROUP BY on a table with 7.8mil rows. The GROUP BY should, in my case, select distinct 'creatorId' and 'dutyCycleLevel' and do the operations accordingly.

Comment: Add the correct INNER and/or LEFT joins and you'll avoid the effects of a  big & slow cross join of 4 tables.

Comment: Now I understand. I had no idea that it first creates the Cartesian product of the 4 tables and only then the grouping occurs...

Comment: So I would INNER JOIN the two columns i.e. INNER JOIN table <table_1_alias> db.table1alias.table1col = db.table2.table2col AND db.table1alias.table1col2 = db.table2.table2col2.

Comment: I would recommend you create an intermediary table: Insert the DISTINCT rows from the larger table. Use that to build the final table. Definitely INNER JOIN on those two columns (creatorId and dutyCycleLevel)

Comment: perhaps something like `... FROM (select distinct creatorId, dutyCycleLevel, accel_x, accel_y, accel_z from SHED5.accel) a
LEFT JOIN SHED5.location l on (a.creatorId = l.creatorId and a.dutyCycleLevel = l.dutyCycleLevel)
LEFT JOIN SHED5.wifi w on (a.creatorId = w.creatorId and a.dutyCycleLevel = w.dutyCycleLevel)
LEFT JOIN SHED5.battery b on (a.creatorId = b.creatorId and a.dutyCycleLevel = b.dutyCycleLevel)
GROUP BY a.creatorId, a.dutyCycleLevel, l.timestamp, b.pluggedInDescription`